# mysql: Creating a Query using AND Operator between same row in a Table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Currently I am working on a Wordpress Project and i am stuck on this query creation for approx one week any help will be appreciated

Below is a basic example what i am trying to do:-

```
"SELECT * FROM test WHERE name='late' AND (id='test_user' AND id='test_client' AND id='test_owner')";
```

The Problem I am Facing is when i run this above query it does not bring any data for me This is what my current retirement is i am creating a filter function and this is what i have to do any way.

Comment: Seriously how can `name` be `test_user` and `test_client` in the same time?

Comment: Would you please show the data?

Comment: Maybe you just need to replace `AND` with `OR` and `OR` with `AND`?

Comment: strings are not compared with '=', replace '=' with 'like'

Comment: use or instead and not and

Answer (score 1):

You placed AND and OR incorrectly. Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE activity = 'late'
AND (name = 'test_user' OR name = 'test_client' OR name = 'test_owner');
```

Comment: I already applied what you mentioned here but the data which i want to generate should be as narrow and dense as possible so its only and condition which i have to place there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE activity='late' 
OR name IN ('test_user', 'test_client', 'test_owner')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `IN` Operator

```
"SELECT * FROM test WHERE activity='late' OR  name in ( 'test_user','test_client','test_owner')";
```